# How to Create a Product Grid in Storefront Using hyva-themes/module-magento2-admin Module?

Tags: custom-admin-grid, hyva, hyva-themesmagento2-default-theme

**Question:**
I've been using hyva-themes/module-magento2-admin to simplify admin area grid development in Magento 2, and it's been fantastic. Now, I'm looking to leverage the same module to create a product grid on the storefront.

While the module excels in the admin area, I'm unsure about its extension to the frontend. I've scoured the docs and explored its features, but I can't find a clear example or guide for this specific task.

**Query:** Are there any experts familiar with hyva-themes/module-magento2-admin who could provide pointers, code snippets, or instructions for implementing a product grid on the storefront? I want to maintain the efficiency it brings to admin development. Any help, whether in code or guidance, would be highly appreciated.

Repo: https://github.com/hyva-themes/magento2-hyva-admin

Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://github.com/hyva-themes/magento2-hyva-admin/issues/74